# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I get this error when I search for 'andkk':

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res.map is not a function

here's my code:

```
state = {
  ListBook: [],
  SaveQuery: '',
}

SearchBook = (query) => {
  if (query.trim() !== '') {
    BooksAPI.search(query).then((res) => {
      res.map(book => (this.props.allBooks.filter((b) => b.id === book.id).map(b => book.shelf = b.shelf)))
      if (res && res.length) this.setState({
        ListBook: res,
        SaveQuery: query
      })
      if (res.error) this.setState({
        ListBook: [],
        SaveQuery: 'query'
      })
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      ListBook: []
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code and checked `console.log(typeof res)`?

Comment: res is probably not an array. map is only defined for arrays.

Comment: usually `res` is an object. `map` is only a prototype of `Array`.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still learning but that's what i see in the console:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res.map is not a function
    at Search.js:16

Comment: res
:
{error: "empty query", items: Array(0)}

Comment: You want `res.items.map`. `res` is an object, and `map` is for mapping array items.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it:

```
BooksAPI.search(query).then((res) => {
          if (res && res.length) this.setState({ListBook: res, SaveQuery: query})
          if (res.error) return res
res.map(book => (this.props.allBooks.filter((b) => b.id === book.id).map(b => book.shelf = b.shelf)))
```